# Making a note with a double stem in MusiXTeX

Tags: music, musixtex

How would I make notes with both a stem down and a stem up (like the first 7 notes below) in [MusiXTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf)?

[image]

From [section 2.4.1](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf#page=28) I know to give a note a stem up (e.g. `\qu`), a stem down (`\ql`) or automatic stem direction (`\qa`). But the whole manual doesn't mention 'double stem' anywhere. I searched every occurence of 'stem' without any results. None of the examples from the manuals show anything like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use back-skipping using `\bsk` or – as you've already noticed in your answer – zero-width notes. Personally I think back-skipping is easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}

% back skipping
\begin{music}
  \startextract
  \NOTEs
  \qup j\bsk\qlp j
  \en
  \NOTEs
  \qup j\bsk\qlp j
  \en
  \NOtes
  \Tqbu jji\bsk\bsk\bsk
  \Tqbl jji
  \en
  \NOtes
  \Tqbu jkl\bsk\bsk\bsk
  \Tqbl jih
  \en
  \endextract
\end{music}

% zero width notes
\begin{music}
  \startextract
  \NOTEs
  \zqup j\qlp j
  \en
  \NOTEs
  \zqup j\qlp j
  \en
  \NOtes
  \ibu0j{-1}\ibl1j{-1}\zqu j\qb1j\zqu j\qb1j\tbu0\tbl1\zqu i\qb1i
  \en
  \NOtes
  \ibu0j1\ibl1j{-2}\zqu j\qb1j\zqu k\qb1i\tbu0\tbl1\zqu l\qb1h
  \en
  \endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
\notes
\zhu N   % no width; half note; stem up
\hl N    % half note; stem up
\en
```

Since the notes are the same they fall over each other and you only see one. It looks pretty much the same as a single `\hl N`:

[image]

But, as this isn't mentioned anywhere in the manual and there are still two note heads, I don't think this is the recommended approach.

Comment: This reflects the exact meaning, doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg if you look at it that way, yes... What I'm worried about is that for some reasons the two notes aren't place at the exact same position in some cases (although I don't know if this could happen). In such cases, it would look weird.